# Interface for all numbers?

Tags: go, generics

The [generics tutorial](https://go.dev/doc/tutorial/generics) uses this:

```
type Number interface {
    int64 | float64
}
```

Is there no interface for all integer and float types in golang?

Comment: You can declare your own set using `Signed` and `Float` from here: https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/exp/constraints or don't use `constraints` package and define the set from the builtins entirely.

Comment: It should be `Integer` and `Float`.

Comment: As illustrated by the above comments, it's not clear whether "all numbers" would include unsigned types or not. That's probably why it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare a new type constraint which integrates `constraints.Float` and `constraints.Integer`.

```golang
// Number is a custom type set of constraints extending the Float and Integer type set from the experimental constraints package.
type Number interface {
    constraints.Float | constraints.Integer
}
```